# Предупреждение C4239: nonstandard extension used

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
class A
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<A> Ptr;
};

void f(A::Ptr&)
{
}

int main() 
{
    f(A::Ptr(new A));
}
```

Почему возникает предупреждение

> warning C4239: nonstandard extension used: 'argument': conversion from 'std::shared_ptr' to 'A::Ptr &'

А если сделать так то предупреждение не возникает:

```
int main() 
{
    A::Ptr a(new A);
    f(a);
}
```

Как такое использование может привести к ошибке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Функция описана как получающая *неконстантную* ссылку, а передаете вы в нее временное значение (грубо говоря, rvalue). VC++ разрешает такие действия, но именно как нестандартное расширение.

Во втором случае вы передаете ссылку на переменную, т.е. ссылку на lvalue.

Не думаю, что в функции вы как-то меняете входную ссылку - иначе какой смысл передавать в нее временный объект? - так что можете написать

```
void f(const A::Ptr&)
```

Это позволит не прибегать к нестандартным расширениям.

Comment: Добавлю, что с выходом VS2017 (15.5) и появлением флага `/permissive-` (выставляется по-умолчанию для новых проектов) компилятор VC++ больше не разрешает такие действия и выдает `error C2664`.

Comment: @VTT Спасибо за уточнение; не знал.